# Objective C. What's wrong with this UIButton image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a set of UIButtons mapped out in IB. I want to randomly add images to a few buttons for each round of an education game.

You can see some images stashed at the top of the page:

[image]

As you can also see, the images in the buttons are blue. So, what am I doing wrong (i.e. why are they blue?)? Are they being set as background images?

I'm adding the images as follows:

```
    int tmpTag0 = [[currentButtonArray objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
    UIButton *tmpButton0 = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:tmpTag0];
    [tmpButton0 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:temp1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

........

    int tmpTag4 = [[currentButtonArray objectAtIndex:4] integerValue];
    UIButton *tmpButton4 = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:tmpTag4];
    [tmpButton4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:temp5] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

currentButtonArray is an array of 5 random button indexes that correspond to 5 button tags.

Thanks very much for any ideas.

What I'm seeing when I look for UIButton in Xcode help:

[image]

UPDATE: 
With help from folks below, this worked for me:

```
int tmpTag0 = [[currentButtonArray objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
UIButton *tmpButton0 = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:tmpTag0];
UIImage *buttonImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:temp1];
buttonImage0 = [buttonImage0 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
[tmpButton0 setImage:buttonImage0 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Please read the document called "Buttons" in the Xcode documentation. It explains this.

Comment: I've marked up my question with what I'm seeing with the Xcode docs.. i.e.. not much. could you please provide a URL, or instructions for idiots :)

Comment: If you search "buttons" in the documentation, you should see something called, "Appearance of Buttons" in the SDK guides at the bottom of the list. Look at that.

Comment: You'd be blue too, if you were cooped up in that tiny little phone.

Comment: yep. I'm definitely a plus size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I [quote](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIButton.html):

> Using the Image field, you can specify an image to appear within the
>   content of your button. ... Note that this image will be automatically
>   rendered as a template image within the button, unless you explicitly
>   set its rendering mode to UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal.

So, probably:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:temp5] 
                   imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
[tmpButton4 setImage:image ...
```

(etc)

Comment: great. Thanks.. could you please point me to the documentation you quote from?

Comment: Oh, the link is hidden underneath the word 'quote' — it's this: https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIButton.html (scroll down to the heading 'Images')

Comment: Thanks Tommy, between your answer and the docs -- thanks too @rdelmar -- I got it.. I'm posting the result in my question..

Answer (score 0):

More elegant option, in my opinion, could be to go to `UIButton`'s property inspector in interface builder and select `Custom` under `Type`. The blue version that you are referring to only appears if you keep the default `System` type for your buttons. Than you can initialize the buttons as usual, either by code or inside the interface builder.